# Connecting SQL 2008 and Web server 2008 using directly connected Ethernet cable on 2nd network cards

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to provide a direct connection for my SQL server on the 2nd network card that connects directly to a 2008 Web server.  I'm aware that I would want to use a crossover cable and I wouldn't want to use a default gateway on either side of the connection.  However I'm not sure what else I would need to configure to make this work well.  Any Ideas anyone?

This would be a temporary solution until I could get a vlan in place.

The goal is to eliminate all other traffic as well as isolate the communication between the 2 servers.

Thanks In Advance

Phygg

Answer (score 2):

Assign IP addresses to each inferface, and use the ip address of the sql server to connect.

Comment: Wow - that's it?  Seems pretty straight forward.  I wan't sure what I would have to do in SQL to make it work properly.

Comment: Well, the SQL server will either need to be listening on all interfaces, or specifically on that IP address.  I would set it up on all interfaces/ips just to not have issues.

Comment: Well because I have a 2nd web server, So here's what I did.   I used an extra switch to plug the 3 machines into.  I put all 3 servers'2nd network cards a different subnet, and plugged them into the switch to nowhere.  As soon as there was a 2nd connection with SQL - it brought it down, lost network connectivity with main network card on SQL server.  I must be missing something - any idea?

Answer (score 0):

We've decided to setup VLAN instead becasue it is more stable and a better technology anyway

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer as accepted, it lets the system know not to recycle it periodically and helps others know what resolved it.